# Why does it look like the skin of my character model is peeling when I join the hands to the mesh in Blender 2.82?

Tags: modifiers, sculpting, normals, topology, dynamic-topology

I'm nearing the end of my first male base mesh sculpt in Blender 2.82, but when I either boolean or just join the hands to the arms there's a sort of skin peeling effect. This continues all over the body if I try just using the smooth brush over the affected area. It looks like a normals problem, but I can't tell for sure.

I've tried deleting all but a tiny bit of the intersecting meshes to simplify the joining operation, I've tried dynatopo sculpting over this peeling seam then smoothing, and it does not work.

I feel that I've tried everything short of sculpting the hand again from the end of the arm. If someone could explain what is happening and save me the trouble of having to do that, I would be ridiculously grateful!

[image]

Comment: Can't be certain with the screenshot, but it looks like you've got two nearly identical, superposed meshes. Since you used a boolean, make sure to Hide the boolean operator (the one you selected in the Object  field of the modifier)

Comment: That was exactly the problem! Thank you so so much! I didn't know the applied boolean copies the target object. I banged my head against a wall for a week on this one and ii's so simple! Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't COPY it ! The think is, it doesn't DELETE it, and that's the whole point of using a modifier ; so you can later modify the target, and the modifications will be transmited to the  boolean object (unless you Apply the modifier, of course)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've got two nearly identical, superposed meshes.

Since you used a boolean, make sure to Hide the boolean target (the one you selected in the Object field of the modifier)